# LinkedIn integration to retrieve company posts

Tags: c#, api, oauth, widget, linkedin-api

I am trying to find if it is possible to retrieve the last 4 posts for example from a specific company that is on LinkedIn. Lets say IBM 
https://www.linkedin.com/company/ibm

I tried to use the docs provided by Microsoft about authorization / accessToken but looks like everything is about sending my website user to a log-in credentials page and redirecting back to my website. I do not want to ask usernames from a specific user to get his information... I just want to do something like facebook/twitter widget and just get my company posts in a JSON string.

Any clue if that is even possible? I tried many libraries and API calls but looks like everything circles around having the user to be authenticated thru a website before doing API calls... I don't see how to pragamatically authenticate thru client id / client secret before retrieving

```
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#get_update
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs
https://github.com/SparkleNetworks/LinkedInNET (looks like it is 
deprecated)
```

I also don't see any built-in widget that display this information:
https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins

Comment: Are you reading before replying? I just said that I do not want to pop users to authenticate. Everything in the oauth2 doc is about that.

Comment: ah, sorry - missed that in my haste

Comment: @viniciuscd, I'm trying to do exactly the same thing and I'm totally lost. Did you manage to find a way to do so?