# How to retrieve a company's recent posts in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin-api

I work for a digital marketing company (lets call it COMPANY_A). I log in as that company. Once inside the LinkedIn envelope I want to grab the most recent posts from a client company (COMPANY_B) and make them available to COMPANY_B's website via WordPress. This might happen through COMPANY_A's Azure machine and some ASP.NET code.

I'm confused about what kind of privilege I need. The impression I get is that `r_organization_social` gives me access to COMPANY_A's social data, not COMPANY_B's. Or is it as simple as authorising COMPANY_A into LinkedIn and then, with all the relevant cookies in place, scraping the required data off COMPANY_B's site?

A question like this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715836/linkedin-integration-to-retrieve-company-posts) but no solution has been offered there.